# Old site migration and keeping links (as aliases)

Tags: path-aliases

I'm migrating an older site into Drupal 7 and have had a lot of success so far. One item where I'm stumped is on links to user profiles. The older system would link to teachers via

`site.edu/faculty.php?PID=FirstnameLastname`

Might there be a way to effectively copy that URL as the page's alias `faculty.php?PID=FirstnameLastname`? And yes, is there a way to escape the http encodings (`?`, `=`, and `&`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real need to escape the URI string.

Here's one way to handle this:

1. In a custom module, implement `hook_menu()`, creating an item for the path 'faculty.php'
2. In your php function callback for the above path, look at the `PID` value, look up the new path (you do have a database table mapping old content to new content, right? :) ), and do a 301 redirect.

Another approach is to do this lookup on all 404 pages with something like the following code in a `hook_init()`:

```
function hook_init() {
  if (!menu_get_item($_GET['q'])) {
    $pid = isset($_GET['PID']) ? $_GET['PID'] : FALSE;

    if ($pid) {
      // lookup new path and 301 to it
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One gotcha on this, is that hook_init() doesn't run on cached pages. Any suggestions for a work around?

Comment: @Richard Did you try the hook_menu thing?  That is really the best option.

Comment: if faculty.php is the only legacy page you need to redirect you could create a faculty.php file in your root and write non-drupal php to redirect to the correct page.

Comment: @MotoTribe, the problem with that is not having access to Drupal's framework, meaning you'd have to write your own database access code (so you can query the db and figure out the destination), essentially duplicating your work.

Comment: you could include the Drupal bootstrap in that file http://www.interworks.com/blogs/jkhalaj/2012/05/01/how-bootstrap-drupal