# If not hook_init(), what can be used for cached pages?

Tags: caching, hooks

I created a module to keep query_string laden links from a client site active (per client's request, background question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/64696/5966)).

This code works wonderfully when I'm logged in (as user 1); however, I have later found that `hook_init()` does not run on cached pages.

Should I place this logic into another hook? Should I take a different approach to intercepting and mapping these legacy links?

```
<?php    
/**
 * Extends hook_init()
 *
 * Intercepts vidID or PID and forwards to the page's proper Drupal node.
 *
 */

function module_init() {


    if (!menu_get_item($_GET['q'])) {

        $pid    = isset($_GET['PID']) ? $_GET['PID'] : FALSE;
        $vidID  = isset($_GET['vidID']) ? $_GET['vidID'] : FALSE;

        if ($pid) {
            // handler code
        }
        elseif ($vidID) {
            // handler code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `preprocess_page` hook

Comment: The important question here is how are you forwarding to the proper page.

Comment: I am sending people to the new node via drupal_goto("node/$nodenumber");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I did take a different approach. In trying to make use of other query string variables, I found it easier to use apache's mod_rewrite. That is, I used Apache's mod_rewrite to turn this `/profile/?id=1234` into this `/provile/id/1234`.

In turn, in Drupal, we added aliases of `profile/id/1234` to the appropriate user profile.

All turned out well. It's a much more managable solution. Old URLs are in tact. Result: everyone's happy.

.htaccess

```
# Rewrite old URLS
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PID=([0-9a-zA-Z]*)
RewriteRule ^faculty/ /faculty/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} vidID=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^videos/ /video/id/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

If a page is cached, it means that it got generated and cached at some point. At this point, your code in `module_init()` did run. If your code generated a redirect (via `drupal_goto()`), this redirect will get cached.

There should not be anything wrong with this scenario, so maybe you should just clear the cache once?

Comment: Would the redirect get cached even if the `if()` condition for creating it is not fulfilled on the page call that got cached?